# How do I change the position of the Locals and Watchers panel in QtCreator?

Tags: debugging, qt, qt-creator

Does anyone know how to change the position of the panel with local variables in QtCreator? When debugging, this panel is on the right side of the screen, but I would really like it to be on the bottom part.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Go to `Window > Views` and uncheck the "Locked" option.
- Move / undock your panels as desired.
- Relock the panels by re-checking the "Locked" option above.

That's where the option is in Qt Creator 2.3 on the Mac. Other platforms / versions may be slightly different.

Comment: I'm using qt-creator 4.4 and this option is currently grayed out

Comment: See @Vorac's answer below for recent Linux.

Answer (score 8):

In QtCreator 3.5:
- place mouse pointer near the top line of the window you want to move
- after ~1 sec window title bar will appear
- move window using drag-n-drop

Answer (score 6):

QtCreator 4.1.9 on Linux:

`Window -> View -> Automatically Hide View Title Bars (un-tick)`

Then drag and drop.

Comment: To enable "View", use "Window -> Show Mode Selector". Then on the left toolbar select debug. This worked on 4.4